# Xcode stuck on "Creating App Store Connect API analysis file..."

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I am trying to upload my app to app store connect. It previously worked using Xcode 10 but since updating to Xcode 11 it just fails every single time. It gets stuck on the "Creating App Store Connect API analysis file..." stage, and then after a while it says "An error occurred uploading to the App Store.".
Previously I had uploaded a build for this version with PencilKit, and then received an email saying that there was an error relating to that. So then I removed PencilKit, and incremented the build number and now I still get an error, but it doesn't send me an email.

Comment: It took 4 hours in this stage. Any news on how to fix this issue. Mine is xcode 12.5.

Answer (score 1):

Just create new certificates for your account..
from `Xcode -> preference -> Accounts -> select your team account -> press manage certificates press (+) to add development certificatte and ios destribution certificate..

then try again and your problem will be solved .

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. But, now when you re-add (or recreate) the same account, the old one is replaced by the new one. So you don't have duplicates. ;)